# accessoryType Checkmark don't work correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When i use `accessoryType = .Checkmark` and select 1st cell in UITableView, 9th and 18th cells are selects too. What i do wrong?

Code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        selectedCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = setList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

I'm trying to make an array with names of cells and if the `checkList[indexPath.row] == ""` I'm add a checkmark, if the `checkList[indexPath.row] == setList[indexPath.row]` then `selectedCell.accessoryType = .None`

Comment: Update your question with the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function and show how you properly set the accessory type only for the cells that should be checked.

Comment: add `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to question

Comment: Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't setting the cell's `accessoryType` like it needs to.

Comment: thanks, i found answer